# SpringBootTest annotation doesn't work in maven test command

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I add annotation SpringBootTest on my test class, it works very well in IDE(intellij), but when I run mvn test command, it seems SpringBootTest annotation doesn't work, because I didn't see spring context is initialized from logs and the auto-wired object is null. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

BTW, I use spring-boot 2.5.6

My test look like
[image]

The pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.compiler/compiler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>22.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- maven私服配置 -->
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Release Repositories</name>
        <url>http://43ac054091.zicp.vip:18081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Snapshot Repositories</name>
        <url>http://43ac054091.zicp.vip:18081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And the log error:

```
    [ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.152 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.jdbctest.ApplicationTest
    [ERROR] selectplaninfo  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'companyDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyDao' defined in file [S:\CDS\forAnton\testSpring\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\target\classes\com\example\jdbctest\dao\CompanyDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyDao' defined in file [S:\CDS\forAnton\testSpring\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\target\classes\com\example\jdbctest\dao\CompanyDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver

[ERROR] run  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'companyDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyDao' defined in file [S:\CDS\forAnton\testSpring\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\target\classes\com\example\jdbctest\dao\CompanyDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'companyDao' defined in file [S:\CDS\forAnton\testSpring\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\target\classes\com\example\jdbctest\dao\CompanyDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ApplicationTest.run » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
[ERROR]   ApplicationTest.selectplaninfo » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContex...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.981 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-09T23:40:09+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/467M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project huatengbase-jdbc-test: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to S:\CDS\forAnton\testSpring\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\huatengbase-jdbc-test-2\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Please add more details ... how does your test look like... how have you called Maven? Log file ? Why using an old version of SB...etc...

Comment: Add pom.xml ,your test case ,error logs you get ...

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for your comments. I shared my test, pom.xml file and log with error.

Comment: That looks like a problem: `Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: Huatengxdb.jdbc.driver.HuatengxdbDriver` another tip... maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.0 is not able to execute JUnit Jupiter based tests.. you have to have at least version 2.22.2 better most recent 3.1.2...